# NLog settings not deleting MaxArchiveDays or MaxArchiveFiles?

Tags: c#, nlog

I have the following NLog config file below. It's set to Archive every day and initially I had just the MaxArchiveFiles. Now I would like to keep only X amount of days of archived files and found the info that says MaxArchiveDays is available in v4.7 and up. So, I upgraded to v4.7 but now it doesn't seem to archive either on Days or File number.

Anyone see anything wrong with this config file with NLog v4.7?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      autoReload="true" 
      throwExceptions="true">

  <variable name="LogDirectory" value="D:/Logs/HRImport"/>

  <targets async="true">

    <target name="DefaultTarget"
      xsi:type="File"
      fileName="${LogDirectory}/LogFile.log"
      encoding="utf-8"
      layout="${longdate} | ${callsite} | ${message}"
      archiveFileName="${LogDirectory}/Archive/${shortdate}_log.{#}.log"
      archiveAboveSize="3145728"   
      archiveEvery="Day"
      archiveNumbering="Rolling"
      maxArchiveFiles="3"
      maxArchiveDays="2"
    />
    <!--1 meg: 1048576 -->

    <target name="ConsoleTarget"
      xsi:type="Console"
      layout="${longdate} ${logger:shortName=True} ${message}${onexception:EXCEPTION OCCURRED\:${exception:format=type,message,StackTrace,method:maxInnerExceptionLevel=8:innerFormat=type,message,StackTrace,method}}"
    />

  </targets>

  <rules>
    <logger name="defaultLogger" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="DefaultTarget,ConsoleTarget" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

** UPDATE **

```
<target name="DefaultTarget"
      xsi:type="File"
      fileName="${LogDirectory}/LogFile.log"
      encoding="utf-8"
      layout="${longdate} | ${callsite} | ${message}"
      archiveFileName="${LogDirectory}/Archive/{#}_log.log"
      archiveNumbering="DateAndSequence"
      archiveAboveSize="3145728"   
      archiveEvery="Day"
      maxArchiveFiles="3"
      maxArchiveDays="2"
    />
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is the use of `${shortdate}`:

```
archiveFileName="${LogDirectory}/Archive/${shortdate}_log.{#}.log"
archiveNumbering="Rolling"
```

When using Layout in `archiveFileName` then it must be very static. Only `{#}` should contain the dynamic part.

Instead try this:

```
archiveFileName="${LogDirectory}/Archive/{#}_log.log"
archiveNumbering="DateAndSequence"
```

See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/FileTarget-Archive-Examples

Comment: I posted what I changed it to but still didn't delete any files out of the Archive folder. I did delete the current day LogFile.log and it recreated that but didn't delete anything. Do you see anything I might have missed?

Comment: @Caverman Well copy pasted your config (with the updated file-target-config), and it nicely deletes when too many files in the archive-folder. `maxArchiveFiles="3"` is working for me. Maybe check if you have deployed the updated NLog.config ? Maybe check the internal logger for any issues ?

Comment: Remember my new suggested configuration will generate files with a different filename in the archive-folder, and will probably not delete files generated by the old configuration. But no guarantees :)

Comment: Ahh....that's probably it. The file structure being different is probably it. Let me see if I can test it out more knowing that.

Comment: Looks like that worked, at least for the number of files. The Max Days I'll have to wait and see since I don't have rights to change the date/time on my work computer.